# Use sub and superscript as [optional] parameters for macro

Tags: math-mode, subscripts, superscripts

I am defining a macro, and would like to run other macro's on any sub/superscripts given to it. For example, I would like to define it such that something like:

```
     \myMacro_{lower}^{upper} -----> \operatorname{something}_\someMacro{lower}^\anotherMacro(upper)
```

Where both sub/super-scripts would be optional. How would this best be done?

---

Prior works:

- [Capture a macro's subscripts/superscripts by the macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/83554/capture-a-macros-subscripts-superscripts-by-the-macro) provides a neat solution when we are just interested in a superscript.
- [How can I capture both superscripts and subscripts after a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118508/how-can-i-capture-both-superscripts-and-subscripts-after-a-macro?rq=1) might be the correct solution to use, but it seems like it might be overly complex - is there a simpler solution that avoids adding the xparse package (as the first solution manages)?

Comment: Something like [Easy command or package for properly formatted integrals?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/174121/16967)

Comment: Thanks, that solves my question. Flagged as duplicate, although I can delete if Tex.SE would prefer.